# Pysark dataframe not filtering out rows when comparing two columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Example of my data

```
event_id    | previous_plan |  new_plan  
       1    |     Null      |   1mo
       2    |     Null      |   1mo
       3    |     1mo       |   1mo
       4    |     6mo       |   6mo
       5    |     Null      |   6mo
       6    |     1mo       |   6mo
       7    |     6mo       |   6mo
```

I want to filter out rows where "previous_plan" = "new_plan". My code is

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.selectExpr("event_id",
              "previous_plan",
              "new_plan") \
   .filter(F.col("previous_plan") != F.col("new_plan"))
```

This should filter out rows with event_id of 3, 4, and 7 to return the updated dataframe

```
event_id    | previous_plan |  new_plan  
       1    |     Null      |   1mo
       2    |     Null      |   1mo
       5    |     Null      |   6mo
       6    |     1mo       |   6mo
```

However, I am still getting all 7 rows. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you please provide the code you use it can be a space problem in one of the row 7 columns value

Answer (score 0):

I needed to also add logic to take into account Nulls. Specifically, Nulls compared to anything will always return false. So we need to filter for rows that dont equal each other (as non-nulls) as well as cases where one or the other column is null but not both.

```
df.filter(
    (F.col("previous_plan") != F.col("new_plan")) | 
    (F.col("previous_plan").isNull() & F.col("new_plan").isNotNull()) |
    (F.col("previous_plan").isNotNull() & F.col("new_plan").isNull())
)
```

Comment: Have a look at the eqNullSafe function: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.eqNullSafe.html